# How do we store a reference to an object in the pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

I am thinking of this solution, but not sure if it is correct.

```cpp
Type* myObjP;

void setSmth(Type& toBePassed) {
  myObjP = *toBePassed;
};
```

Comment: @Evg I wouldn't .. recommend that.

Comment: @Evg The context of the question is too small to suggest a solution that is guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: Store a reference in a pointer?? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toBePassed` is a reference, not a pointer. So you actually need the `&` operator (address of operator), not the `*` operator (dereference operator):

```
myObjP = &toBePassed;
```

Note: You're not really storing a reference in a pointer. You're just storing a regular pointer to the object that is being referenced.

Answer (score 9):

Syntactically speaking, you would need to use:

```
void setSmth(Type& toBePassed) {
  myObjP = &toBePassed; // Addressof operator rather than dereference operator.
}
```

#### Word of Caution

When using such a mechanism, you'll have to be very careful when you dereference `myObjP`. If the object passed to `setSmth` is not alive, dereferencing `myObjP` will cause undefined behavior.

There are more robust mechanisms in the language but it's hard to suggest anything without additional context.

Comment: Not sure how I became the accepted answer. I like yours better than my own.

Comment: @Chipster, got to respect the OP's feeling on that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.
you should use & operator for pass address to pointer.

```
double* myObjP;

void setSmth(double& toBePassed) 
{
    myObjP = &toBePassed;
};

int main()
{
    double testValue{8.0};
    setSmth(testValue);

    if (testValue == *myObjP)
    {
        cout << "We store a reference to an object in the pointer\n";
        cout << "testValue ==> " << testValue << "   " << "*myObjP ==> " << *myObjP<<std::endl;
    }

    std::getchar();

}
```